# React Native - What does pressRetentionOffset do?

Tags: react-native

This is what the [documentation says](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#pressretentionoffset) :

> **pressRetentionOffset** {top: number, left: number, bottom: number,
>   right: number}
>
> When the scroll view is disabled, this defines how far your touch may 
>       move off of the button, before deactivating the button. Once deactivated, 
>       try moving it back and you'll see that the button is once again reactivated! 
>       Move it back and forth several times while the scroll view is disabled. 
>       Ensure you pass in a constant to reduce memory allocations.

But I don't really get it. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like stated [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#hitslop) it defines that if you keep the button pressed and slide your finger away how far you've got to move away to 'unactivate' the button.

Comment: Got it. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

When you touch a button and hold it down swipe away from the button. Even though your finger isn't touching the button but your finger is still pressed on the screen, the button is still active. This is the distance of how far you can do this before the button is no longer active.